# Is This Notorious Website Blocking Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I try to load up this website I get a "Paused in Debugger" message in Chrome.

Comment: _"Paused in debugger"_ means you have set a breakpoint or the code has [`debugger;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) in it somewhere. See also https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

It's because within the code for the site this exists:

```
(function anonymous(
) {
debugger
})
```

Simply looking at where it pauses shows this clearly. You don't even have to look for it, when the code pauses, the dev tools take you straight to it.

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob, I'm pretty familiar with dev tools and JS, but I've never seen a website have that code before. Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Sure, click the debugger’s play button.